# jQuery insert image from controller MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The following

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#secureNavbar').css("display", "none");
    $('#LayoutFooter').css("display", "none");
    if ($('#violationImage').length > 0) {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ReturnImage", "Violation")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#violationImage').html('<img src="data:image/jpg:base64,' + data + '"/>');
                              },
            error: function (response, errorThrown) {
                alert(response.responseText + " - " + errorThrown);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

pulls an image from the controller

```
Function ReturnImage() As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim vImage() As Byte = Nothing
            Dim vMime As String = ""
            strSQL = "SELECT Offence_Image, Mime_Type FROM Warnings WHERE Warning_ID = " & Session("ViolationID")
            Using DS As DataSet = ReturnDataSet_Data(strSQL, Session("HOAID"), False)
                For Each Row As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                    vImage = Row("Offence_Image")
                    vMime = Row("Mime_Type")
                Next
            End Using


            Dim vThumbnail = CreateThumbnail(vImage, 400)
            Dim vData = Convert.ToBase64String(vThumbnail)

            Return Json(vData)


        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex, 172, PageName)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

but the image doesn't load, the properties are

[image: image properties]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you hitting your success function? If so, what is the value of `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `:` when you should be using a `;`.

```
data:image/jpg;base64,
              ^
          This guy
```

For reference, [Data URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: I am soooo glad you were awake on a Friday evening :-) I stared at that for ages and didn't spot it, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You need `data:image/jpg;base64,` <-- semicolon instead of colon before `base64,`

See https://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/WMdwjg for a demo.

Comment: I marked your answer up, but checked the first one (as it's the same and was earlier) as the answer